# при чтении списка из файла функция append() выдаёт None

Tags: python

Я использовал функцию `open()`, чтобы сохранить содержимое списка:

```
my_list = ['1', '2', 'a']

save = open('items.txt', 'w')
save.write(', '.join(my_list))
save.close
```

Нужно добавить сохранённые данные в лист, но при использовании функции `append()` оболочка выдаёт `None`:

```
my_list = []
new = open('items.txt')

# 'items.txt' has "1, 2, a" as a string.

for item in new:
  print(my_list.append(item))
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

`append` модифицирует список и ничего сама по себе не возвращает.

Вот так будет правильно:

```
my_list = ['1', '2', 'a']

with open('items.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(', '.join(my_list))

with open('items.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

new_list = text.split(', ')
print(new_list)
# ['1', '2', 'a']
```

## Чуть подробнее

Работу с файлами лучше через `with` реализовывать, чтобы они автоматически закрывались и не приходилось вызывать метод `close` самому.

Нужно понимать какого типа `new` в твоем примере:

```
type(new) 
# <type 'file'>`
```

Соответственно итерация по `new` будет возвращать строки файла, а не отдельные знаки. Впрочем, код из вопроса не стал бы работать и в противоположном случае, поскольку пробелы и запятые ничем не хуже букв и цифр с точки зрения Python. Мы получили бы список:

```
['1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', 'a']
```

Ну и список в Python является изменяемой структурой данных, `append` добавляет элемент в список и ничего не возвращает (точнее возвращает None, который ты успешно и выводишь на экран).

Answer (score 0):

`close` - это метод, чтобы его вызвать надо написать круглые скобки

```
save.close()
```

тогда файл будет закрыт.